# Refused to get unsafe header "Content-Length" / reading ID3 tags from external mp3's

Tags: javascript, cors, xmlhttprequest, response-headers

I am trying to write a script that loads ID3 tags from an .mp3 file.

After searching for hours, I found [one script](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader) that had a small size and did what I wanted, however I can't get it to work with cross-domain .mp3 files.
I have tried using CSP headers to bypass this, but without luck.

Is there a way to get around this, like downloading the file in the backgrond and showing a progress bar, or can I bypass this another way?

The error I get when loading an external file:

```
Refused to get unsafe header "Content-Length"
```

It's connected to a .getResponseHeader(); as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

Content-Length is currently a safelisted header defined in the CORS spec: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-response-header-name, so the library or browser you are using may be outdated.

There are two things you can try:

1. Use the updated library for [reading ID3 tags](https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags)
2. Follow this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141) to get around the CORS issue