# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch some data from the REST API of HP Alm. It works pretty well with a small curl script—I get my data.

Now doing that with JavaScript, fetch and ES6 (more or less) seems to be a bigger issue. I keep getting this error message:

> Fetch API cannot load . Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' is
> therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 501.
> If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to
> 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I understand that this is because I am trying to fetch that data from within my localhost and the solution should be using [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). I thought I actually did that, but somehow it either ignores what I write in the header or the problem is something else.

So, is there an implementation issue? Am I doing it wrong? I can't check the server logs unfortunately. I'm really a bit stuck here.

```
function performSignIn() {

  let headers = new Headers();

  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

  headers.append('GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS');

  headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(username + ":" + password));

  fetch(sign_in, {
      //mode: 'no-cors',
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch(error => console.log('Authorization failed : ' + error.message));
}
```

I am using Chrome. I also tried using that Chrome CORS Plugin, but then I am getting another error message:

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
> must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
> 'include'. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' is therefore not allowed
> access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
> XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Answer (score 1750, accepted):

This answer covers a lot of ground, so it’s divided into three parts:

- How to use a CORS proxy to avoid *“No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header”* problems
- How to avoid the CORS preflight
- How to fix *“Access-Control-Allow-Origin header must not be the wildcard”* problems

---

**How to use a CORS proxy to avoid *“No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header”* problems**

If you don’t control the server your frontend code is sending a request to, and the problem with the response from that server is just the lack of the necessary `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, you can still get things to work—by making the request through a CORS proxy.

You can easily run your own proxy with code from https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/.
You can also easily deploy your own proxy to Heroku in just 2-3 minutes, with 5 commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere.git
cd cors-anywhere/
npm install
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

After running those commands, you’ll end up with your own CORS Anywhere server running at, e.g., `https://cryptic-headland-94862.herokuapp.com/`.

Now, prefix your request URL with the URL for your proxy:

```
https://cryptic-headland-94862.herokuapp.com/https://example.com
```

Adding the proxy URL as a prefix causes the request to get made through your proxy, which:

1. Forwards the request to `https://example.com`.
2. Receives the response from `https://example.com`.
3. Adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response.
4. Passes that response, with that added header, back to the requesting frontend code.

The browser then allows the frontend code to access the response, because that response with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is what the browser sees.

This works even if the request is one that triggers browsers to do a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request, because in that case, the proxy also sends the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers needed to make the preflight succeed.

---

**How to avoid the CORS preflight**

The code in the question triggers a CORS preflight—since it sends an `Authorization` header.

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Even without that, the `Content-Type: application/json` header will also trigger a preflight.

What “preflight” means: before the browser tries the `POST` in the code in the question, it first sends an `OPTIONS` request to the server, to determine if the server is opting-in to receiving a cross-origin `POST` that has `Authorization` and `Content-Type: application/json` headers.

> It works pretty well with a small curl script - I get my data.

To properly test with `curl`, you must emulate the preflight `OPTIONS` the browser sends:

```
curl -i -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000" \
    -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
    -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization' \
    "https://the.sign_in.url"
```

…with `https://the.sign_in.url` replaced by whatever your actual `sign_in` URL is.

The response the browser needs from that `OPTIONS` request must have headers like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  http://127.0.0.1:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
```

If the `OPTIONS` response doesn’t include those headers, the browser will stop right there and never attempt to send the `POST` request. Also, the HTTP status code for the response must be a 2xx—typically 200 or 204. If it’s any other status code, the browser will stop right there.

The server in the question responds to the `OPTIONS` request with a 501 status code, which apparently means it’s trying to indicate it doesn’t implement support for `OPTIONS` requests. Other servers typically respond with a 405 “Method not allowed” status code in this case.

So you’ll never be able to make `POST` requests directly to that server from your frontend JavaScript code if the server responds to that `OPTIONS` request with a 405 or 501 or anything other than a 200 or 204 or if doesn’t respond with those necessary response headers.

The way to avoid triggering a preflight for the case in the question would be:

- if the server didn’t require an `Authorization` request header but instead, e.g., relied on authentication data embedded in the body of the `POST` request or as a query param
- if the server didn’t require the `POST` body to have a `Content-Type: application/json` media type but instead accepted the `POST` body as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` with a parameter named `json` (or whatever) whose value is the JSON data

---

**How to fix *“Access-Control-Allow-Origin header must not be the wildcard”* problems**

> <sub>I am getting another error message:</sub>
>
> <sub>The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response</sub>
> <sub>must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is</sub>
> <sub>'include'. Origin '`http://127.0.0.1:3000`' is therefore not allowed</sub>
> <sub>access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the</sub>
> <sub>XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.</sub>

For requests that have credentials, browsers won’t let your frontend JavaScript code access the response if the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is `*`. Instead the value in that case must exactly match your frontend code’s origin, `http://127.0.0.1:3000`.

See [*Credentialed requests and wildcards*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Credentialed_requests_and_wildcards) in the MDN HTTP access control (CORS) article.

If you control the server you’re sending the request to, a common way to deal with this case is to configure the server to take the value of the `Origin` request header, and echo/reflect that back into the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header; e.g., with nginx:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin
```

But that’s just an example; other (web) server systems have similar ways to echo origin values.

---

> I am using Chrome. I also tried using that Chrome CORS Plugin

That Chrome CORS plugin apparently just simplemindedly injects an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header into the response the browser sees. If the plugin were smarter, what it would be doing is setting the value of that fake `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to the actual origin of your frontend JavaScript code, `http://127.0.0.1:3000`.

So avoid using that plugin, even for testing. It’s just a distraction. To test what responses you get from the server with no browser filtering them, you’re better off using `curl -H` as above.

---

As far as the frontend JavaScript code for the `fetch(…)` request in the question:

```
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
```

Remove the lines above. The `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers are *response* headers. You never want to send them in requests. The only effect of that is to trigger a browser to execute a preflight.

Comment: Superb answer, my issue was the remote server not responding to OPTIONS requests, so after fiddling about with requests and headers for what seemed like ages I resolved it by removing the headers `Content-Type` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` - thank you!

Comment: Fantastic answer to a common problem. FWIW, we had server responding with 405 (Method not supported) when adding a 'Authorization: Bearer' header to a request, so the fix was to move the token to a POST field instead as control of the server response to the OPTIONS check was not possible in the time frame given by the client.

Comment: Actually after upload the new version of extension to the Azure DevOps, you have to update rights for it in the https://dev.azure.com/{your_organization}/_settings/extensions?tab=installed

when you add new scopes "scopes": ["vso.build"] in the manifest file.

Comment: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` is now no longer usable. The client will now receive a `403 Forbidden` error - unless the developer explicitly requests to get **temporarily** passed. Here is the announcement: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/301. I'd suggest to simply remove the `cors-anywhere` reference from the answer since it's no longer useful.

Comment: the part of "xxx-Credentials: true " is updated. I think it is stopped to allow access CORS calls when -Origin is set matches the browser url but different to the HTTP call endpoint.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann cors-anywhere can still be used with a challenge as written in your link. BTW, Heroku closes the free Dynos in november, so you probably have to pay for the proxy service then.

Comment: this is pretty neat post https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/ about the same problem

Comment: I've extended this to work with aws_lambda and published it as a terraform module: [lambda-cors-anywhere](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/n-ae/lambda-cors-anywhere/aws/latest). It basically fetches this public repo & adds the lambda wrapper and deploys a lambda function to work with your customized allow origins.

Answer (score 233):

This error occurs when the client URL and server URL don't match, including the port number. In this case you need to enable your service for CORS which is cross origin resource sharing.

If you are hosting a Spring REST service then you can find it in the blog post *[CORS support in Spring Framework](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)*.

If you are hosting service using a Node.js server then

1. Stop the Node.js server.
2. `npm install cors --save`
3. Add following lines to your server.js

```
const cors=require("cors");
const corsOptions ={
   origin:'*', 
   credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
   optionSuccessStatus:200,
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions)) // Use this after the variable declaration
```

Comment: `including the port number` :(

Comment: Note: you also need to remove your `mode: 'no-cores'` settings from your `fetch()`  options on the client. Your JSON body won't be sent unless `mode: 'cores'` in your request.

Comment: This question is actually about making a request.  So assume you don't have access to the REST server?  Is there no way to make a request?

Answer (score 163):

The problem arose because you added the following code as the ***request*** header in your front-end:

```
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
```

Those headers belong to the ***response***, not request. So **remove** them, including the line:

```
headers.append('GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS');
```

Your request had `'Content-Type: application/json'`, hence triggered what is called CORS preflight. This caused the browser sent the request with the OPTIONS method. See [CORS preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) for detailed information.

Therefore in your **back-end**, you have to handle this preflighted request by returning the response headers which include:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Origin, Content-Type, Accept
```

Of course, the actual syntax depends on the programming language you use for your back-end.

In your front-end, it should be like so:

```
function performSignIn() {
    let headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(username + ":" +  password));
    headers.append('Origin','http://localhost:3000');

    fetch(sign_in, {
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch(error => console.log('Authorization failed: ' + error.message));
}
```

Comment: This should be the top answer - I really dislike the idea of bypassing CORS, particularly by routing it through a third party.

Comment: hey, whats 'Header()' please?

Comment: @mitsu If you refer to the line : let headers = new Headers(); above, then it is an interface of fetch API to do actions with http request or response headers. Visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers to get the details as well as examples on using it.

Comment: Note that we don't have to specify the `OPTIONS` method to allow. I.e., `Access-Control-Allow-Methods : GET, POST` would be enough; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66926518/10027592).

Answer (score 27):

In my case, I use the below solution.

**Front-end or Angular**

```
post(
    this.serverUrl, dataObjToPost,
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
           'Content-Type':  'application/json',
         })
    }
)
```

**back-end (I use PHP)**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
print_r($request);
```

Answer (score 15):

Adding `mode:no-cors` can avoid CORS issues in the API.

```
fetch(sign_in, {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch(error => console.log('Authorization failed : ' + error.message));
}
```

Comment: It gives error `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: When adding `mode:no-cors` to my PUT request, I got the following error:
`TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': 'PUT' is unsupported in no-cors mode.`
So it appears this doesn't work for PUT, if you are wondering.

Comment: mode: 'no-cors', helped me

Answer (score 10):

Using `dataType: 'jsonp'` worked for me.

```
   async function get_ajax_data(){
       var _reprojected_lat_lng = await $.ajax({
                                type: 'GET',
                                dataType: 'jsonp',
                                data: {},
                                url: _reprojection_url,
                                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    console.log(jqXHR)
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    console.log(data);

                                    // note: data is already json type, you
                                    //       just specify dataType: jsonp
                                    return data;
                                }
                            });


 } // function
```

Answer (score 10):

If your API is written in `ASP.NET Core`, then please follow the below steps:

- Install the *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors* package.
- Add the below line in the ConfigureServices method in file *Startup.cs*:

  ```
  services.AddCors();
  ```
- Add the below line in the *Configure* method in file *startup.cs*:

  ```
  app.UseCors(options =>
       options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
              .AllowAnyHeader()
              .AllowAnyMethod());
  ```
- Make sure you add this after - `app.UseRouting();`

  Refer to the below image(from MSDN) to see the middleware order:

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ4yT.png

Comment: add before UseRouting?  are you sure? All the other references says the opposite, eg: [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#middleware-order-1)

Answer (score 8):

Just my two cents... regarding *How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header” problems*

For those of you working with php at the backend, deploying a "CORS proxy" is as simple as:

1. create a file named 'no-cors.php' with the following content:

   ```
   $URL = $_GET['url'];
   echo json_encode(file_get_contents($URL));
   die();
   ```
2. on your front end, do something like:

   ```
   fetch('https://example.com/no-cors.php' + '?url=' + url)
     .then(response=>{*/Handle Response/*})`
   ```

Answer (score 8):

Possible causes of CORS issues

- Check your server-side *access* headers: [Refer to this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
- Check what request header is received from the server in the browser. The below image shows the headers

  [image]
- If you are using the `fetch` method and trying to access the cross-origin request make sure `mode:cors` is there. Refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- Sometimes if there is an issue in the program also you are getting the CORS issue, so make sure your code is working properly.
- Make sure to handle the `OPTION` method in your API.

Answer (score 6):

Faced this issue in my react/express app. Adding the below code in `server.js` (or your server file name) fixed the issue for me. Install cors and then

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://example.com', // use your actual domain name (or localhost), using * is not recommended
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Accept', 'x-client-key', 'x-client-token', 'x-client-secret', 'Authorization'],
    credentials: true
}))
```

Now you can make straightforward API calls from your front-end without having to pass any additional parameters.

Comment: I am new to react, due to an oppurtunity had to build a react app, may I know how to identify what my server file name is ??

Comment: in your backend dir, you can search the entire dir for `.listen` method, that will be most likely the server file listening/running your backend on a specific port

Answer (score 5):

In December 2021, Chrome 97, the `Authorization: Bearer ...` is not allowed unless it is in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` preflight response (ignores `*`).  It produced this warning:

```
[Deprecation] authorization will not be covered by the wildcard symbol (*)
```

See: *[Chrome Enterprise release notes, Chrome 97](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7679408#corsAuthMis)*

It also appears to enforce the same restriction on `*` on `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.  If you want to revive `*`-like behavior now that it is blocked, you'll likely have to read the requester's origin and return it as the allowed origin in the preflight response.

In some cases, a library may drop the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header when there is some other invalid credential (example: an expired [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token)).  Then, the browser shows the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" error instead of the actual error (which in this example could be an expired JWT).  Be sure that your library doesn't drop the header and confuse the client.

Answer (score 3):

With [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js), if you are using routers, make sure to add CORS before the routers. Otherwise, you'll still get the CORS error. Like below:

```
const cors = require('cors');

const userRouter = require('./routers/user');

expressApp = express();
expressApp.use(cors());
expressApp.use(express.json());
expressApp.use(userRouter);
```

Answer (score 3):

#### For those using ASP.NET Core:

In my case, I was using JavaScript to make a blob from an image stored on the API (the server), so the URL was pointing to that resource. In that API's `program.cs` class, I already had a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) policy, but it didn't work.

After I read the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#usecors-and-usestaticfiles-order) (read the first paragraph) about this issue, it is said that if you want to access a resource on the server, by using JavaScript (which is what I was trying to do), then you must call the `app.UseCors();` ***before*** the `app.UseStaticFiles();` which is typically the opposite.

My *program.cs* file:

```
const string corsPolicyName = "ApiCORS";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(corsPolicyName, policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7212");
    });
});

...

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(settings =>
{
    settings.DisplayRequestDuration();
    settings.EnableTryItOutByDefault();
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors(corsPolicyName); //  This should be above the UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(); //  Below the UseCors();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseApiCustomExceptionHandler();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) as the back-end and [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)) & [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) as the front-end within a development environment in [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS), you need to run both sides under [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS). Below is what finally worked for me (after many hours of deep dive and testing):

**Step 1: Create an SSL certificate**

Just follow the steps from *[How to get HTTPS working on your local development environment in 5 minutes](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/)*.

You will end up with a couple of files to be used as credentials to run the HTTPS server and React web:

```
server.key & server.crt
```

You need to copy them in the root folders of both the front and back ends (in a *production* environment, you might consider copying them in folder *./ssh* for the back-end).

**Step 2: Back-end setup**

I read a lot of answers proposing the use of 'cors' package or even setting ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'), which is like saying: "Hackers are welcome to my website". Just do like this:

```
import express from 'express';
const emailRouter = require('./routes/email');  // in my case, I was sending an email through a form in React
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

const app = express();
const port = 8000;

// CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers to support Cross-site HTTP requests
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://localhost:3000");
    next();
});

// Routes definition
app.use('/email', emailRouter);

// HTTPS server
const credentials = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt')
};

const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Back-end running on port ${port}`);
});
```

In case you want to test if the https is OK, you can replace the httpsServer constant by the one below:

```
https.createServer(credentials, (req: any, res: any) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world from SSL\n");
}).listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`HTTPS server listening on port ${port}...`);
});
```

And then access it from a web browser:   https://localhost:8000/

**Step 3: Front-end setup**

This is the Axios request from the React front-end:

```
    await axios.get(`https://localhost:8000/email/send`, {
        params: { /* Whatever data you want to send */ },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    })
```

And now, you need to launch your React web in HTTPS mode using the credentials for SSL we already created. Type this in your macOS terminal:

```
HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=server.crt SSL_KEY_FILE=server.key npm start
```

At this point, you are sending a request from an HTTPS connection at port 3000 from your front-end, to be received by an HTTPS connection at port 8000 by your back-end. CORS should be happy with this ;)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to add a custom header middleware below all the existing middleware. I think some middleware might conflict with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header and try to set it according to their needs.

So the code would be something like this:

```
app.use(cors());

....all other middleware here

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
...your routes
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:

```
credentials: 'include',
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the web server prevented the "OPTIONS" method

Check your web server for the options method

- Apache: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=ibm10735209
- web tier: 4.4.6 Disabling the Options Method https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e10144/getstart.htm#HSADM174
- [nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx): https://medium.com/@hariomvashisth/cors-on-nginx-be38dd0e19df

> I'm using "webtier"
>
> /www/webtier/domains/[domainname]/config/fmwconfig/components/OHS/VCWeb1/httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^OPTIONS
  RewriteRule .* . [F]
</IfModule>
```

change to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine off
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^OPTIONS
  RewriteRule .* . [F]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this error several times over the past few years -- seemingly showing up out of the blue in a previously functioning website.

I determined that Chrome (and possibly other browsers) can return this error when there is some unrelated error that occurs on the server that prevents it from processing the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) request (and prior to returning an HTTP 500 error).

These all occurred in a [.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core) environment, and I am not sure if it would happen in other environments.

Anyway, if your code has functioned before, and seems correct, consider debugging to find if there is some other error that is firing before you go crazy trying to solve an error that isn't really there.

Answer (score 1):

**For a [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) backend I use this :)**

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "YOUR-DOMAIN.TLD"); // Update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

For more details: *[CORS on ExpressJS](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)*

Answer (score 1):

**Using WebAPI build in .Net Core 6.0**

None of the above worked for me...  This did it

```
// global cors policy
   app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin 
        .AllowCredentials());
```

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70660054/8767516

Comment: Whose voting this down and for what reason?  As noted, for webAPI in 6.0, This worked for my use and it may help someone...  some of you people really need to get a grip on your ego

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution to remove No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Install django cors headers

> pip install django-cors-headers

Modify settings.py file

> add this in INSTALLED_APPS -> 'corsheaders'

Add client address which are allowed to use the server. This is the basically the react app local server address. This should be a new line means not inside any list or dict. Outside of all.

> CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000']

Add this in MIDDLEWARE

> 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'

After doing all the work mention above this error would be gone.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

I used axios to send request to django server. Command to install it

> npm install axios

Code to send the request. Putting the code of whole component just add it in App.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';

var data;

const getTheData = () => {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
        .then(res => {
            data = res.data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(err => { })
}

function GetData() {

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={getTheData()}>Get the data</button>
        </div>
    )
    
}

export default GetData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below npm module. This has virtually saved lives.

*https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-cors-proxy*

You're getting a CORS error, for example like the below URL

*https://www.google.co.in/search/list*

After successfully installed(**local-cors-proxy**) global `npm install -g local-cors-proxy` and set proxy URL that CORS URL.
For example, here the below CORS issue getting in localhost. So you need to add the domain name(https://www.google.co.in) and port(--port 8010) for the CORS issue domain.
For more please check the link
*https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-cors-proxy*

```
lcp --proxyUrl https://www.google.co.in --port 8010
```

After successfully set, it will generate the local proxy URL like below.

*http://localhost:8010/proxy*

Use that domain name in your project API URL.

API full URL:

*http://localhost:8010/proxy/search/list*

To get without a CORS issue response in your local project.

Comment: HI, I'm trying this package as I'm performing a request from Flutter web app running on `localhost:5000` to Node.js server running on `localhost:3000`. So in my case in the scripts I should put `"proxy": "lcp --proxyUrl http://localhost --port 3000"`and make requests to http://localhost:3000/proxy` right? I still get  the `'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'` error .. AM I doing something wrong or it just won't work from localhost to localhost? Many thanks

Comment: Virtually? Not literally?

Comment: This is partly incomprehensible, e.g. near *"the below CORS issue getting in localhost"*. Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66451426/edit) it? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

I make this mistake a lot of times, and because of it, I've made a "check-list" to all of you.

- Enable [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on your project: If you're using [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) (by example) you can use:

  ```
  npm install cors;
  import cors from 'cors';
  app.use(cors());
  ```
- You can manually set the headers like this (if you want it):

  ```
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authortization');
      res.setHeader('Acces-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
  ```
- Remember to add *http://* to your API link in your frontend project, some browsers like Chrome *do not* accept a request using CORS if the request URL isn't HTTP or HTTPS:

  ```
  http://localhost:3000/api
  ```
- Check if your project is using a *proxy.config.js* file. See *[Fixing CORS errors with Angular CLI proxy](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fixing-cors-errors-with-angular-cli-proxy-e5e0ef143f85)*.

Comment: Isn't a `}`missing?

Comment: Acces-Control == Access-Control

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70230578/edit) (change) your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was dumb as hell... Your allowed origin shouldn't have a slash at the end.

E.g., https://example.com`/` -> https://example.com

Answer (score 0):

in case if you are calling api developed in php using react js you need to put following code in php file

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered, but I have a specific case that some other developer may fall in, too.

I had the same issue and I kept debugging it for hours, and none of the answers on StackOverflow (or other forums) seemed to work.

The issue is that I was using *Kong* as my API gateway and I didn't set OPTIONS as an accepted method

***kong.yaml:***

```
_format_version: "2.1"
_transform: true
services:
  - name: api
    url: http://backend:8393
    routes:
      - name: api
        methods:
          - PUT
          - POST
          - GET
          - DELETE
          - PATCH
          - OPTIONS // I didn't have this at first

        paths:
          - /api
```

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same cross-origin blocking issue while writing such code within a browser extension. Write the following code before making any such calls, you wont have to worry about headers, it will resolve everything.
After the following code, you can make as many cross origin calls to `*.example.com` as you like in that session.

```
import Browser from 'webextension-polyfill'
Browser.permissions.request({ origins: ["https://*.example.com"] })
```

It will pop up a browser notification once at the beginning of the session seeking permissions of the user to access `https://*.example.com`, then you are done.
For me one extra pop-up isn't hampering user experience much, if not gives a sense of greater trustworthiness.

Answer (score -1):

When the client used to call our backend service from his host username.companyname.com, he used to get the above error

Two things are required:

1. while sending back the response, send the header whose key is *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* and value is `*`:

   ```
    context.Writer.Header()["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = []string{"*"} // Important to avoid a CORS error
   ```
2. Use the [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29) CORS library to set **AllowCredentials** to false and **AllowAllOrigins** to true.

   [image]

Comment: ***Please*** provide the code as text, not as an image. You can [change](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69281392/edit) your answer  (*"next time"* is completely unacceptable). See e.g. *[Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040/)* Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

For Java-Spring, @CrossOrigin annotation is fixed my issue.
You can place it on top of your @PostMapping,@PutMapping etc. annotation

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@PostMapping
```

Answer (score -2):

There was a simple solution but I struggled for around 3 hours and got the answer. In my case, I wrote all APIs in PHP for Android and it's working fine, but when I tried to reuse all APIs for the Website so I got the below error.

Access to fetch at 'My API' from origin 'from localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I just added these three lines to my server API and got a response.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Password");
```

You can change your header's name according to what you are passing.

May this help you.

Answer (score -4):

Try adding all these headers in this code below ***Before every route, you define in your app, not after the routes***

```
app.use((req, res, next) =>{
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,Accept, Authortization');  
res.setHeader('Acces-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
```

Answer (score -5):

If you are getting this error while deploying React app to netlify, use these steps.

step 1: Create `netlify.toml` file in the root folder of your react app.

step 2: Copy paste this code:

```
`[[redirects]]
    from = "/cors-proxy/*"
    to = ":splat"
    status = 200
    force = true`
```

[image]

step3: update your fetch/axios api this way:

[image]

It took me a while to figure this out.